# How to attach javascript code to this dynamic control textbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i am creating a dynamic textbox control from the code behind... my question is. how can i attach the javascript code to a dynamic created textbox?

here is the code that creates dynamic Textbox.

```
TextBox t = new TextBox();
t.ID = "txtDynamic";
t.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
t.Rows = 7;
```

below is the Javascript....would like to add to the above control created.

```
$('txtDynamic').limit('140','#charsLeft');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ASP.NET WebForms I always try and stay away from referring to IDs in my javascript because the rendered ID may not always be the same as the server side ID.

Use `CssClass` to ensure consistency, and a `.` prefix instead of `#` prefix in your jquery selector.

```
TextBox t = new TextBox();
t.ID = "txtDynamic";
t.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
t.Rows = 7;
t.CssClass = "limit140";

$('.limit140').limit('140','#charsLeft');
```

Answer (score 1):

Ids get changed by the serverside code so you need to use the clientid. Also in your example, you are missing the `#` for the jQuery selector.

```
$('#<%=txtDynamic.ClientID%>').limit('140','#charsLeft');
```

This will only work if the code is inline JavaScript, it will not work in an external file.

If not it is better to set a CSSClass and reference that in the selector.